# Dissolving stream orders using Python rather than VB script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, python-parser, dissolve, hydrology

I've been trying to dissolve streams, using orders programmatically and I came across this VB script. The reason is that if I use ArcGIS dissolve, it merges the confluence of the same orders.

How do I implement this VB script using Python?

```
arc = read all arcs
for order = 1 to maximal order loop
    start_arcs = select all starting arcs of actual order
    for all a in start_arcs loop
        c = a
        do while b = select arc where c.to_code = arc.from_node
            if c.order = b.order then
                c.dissolve = dissolve_counter
                c = b
            else
                dissolve_counter = dissolve_counter + 1
                exit do
            end if
        done
    next a
next order
dissolve all segments with same dissolve counter
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are suggesting that all segments of the same order are a multipart polyline, then use the [Multipart To Single Part (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003r000000) tool which:

> Creates a feature class containing singlepart features generated by
> separating multipart input features.